# Как добавить слаг (например /en/) к текущей странице/записи в WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

Активировал мультисайт на WordPress, добавил два сайта укр и англ версии. В файле header.php внес код:

```
<div class="lang">
     <a href="https://site.com.ua/">UK</a>
     <div class="lang-line"></div>
     <a href="https://site.com.ua/en/">EN</a>
</div>
```

Т. о. при нажатии на UK мы попадаем на укр версию, если на EN - на англ. Подскажите, как сделать так, чтоб находясь не на главной странице (например на странице записи), при нажатии на EN переходило не на главную страницу, а на текущую только англ версию, т.е. чтоб добавлялся слаг /en/ между доменом и слагом самой записи, т.е. вот так - [https://site.com.ua/en/слаг-записи-или-стр/](https://site.com.ua/en/%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80/) ?

Comment: Для мультиязычности нужно использовать плагины, а не мультисайт.

Comment: Плагины мультиязычности решают не только вопрос слагов, а ещё и миллион других вопросов, которые вам пока не приходят в голову.

Answer (score 1):

Такой href формируеться следующим образом.

`<?php global $post;  echo site_url().'/en/'.$post->post_name; ?>`

Но я б вам не рекомендовал, создавать таким образом мультистраницы.
Лучше воспользуйтесь готовыми решениями [polylang](https://uk.wordpress.org/plugins/polylang/) или [wpml](https://wpml.org/ru/). Вероятность того что вы допустите ошибку или что у вас ссылка будет вести на 404 резко уменьшиться.

Comment: Спасибо огромное!